# Does Curb's Jason Alexander know Seinfeld's George Costanza is based on Larry David?

Tags: character, seinfeld, curb-your-enthusiasm

In [S07E03 of Curb](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=curb-your-enthusiasm&episode=s07e03), we hear Jason Alexander saying the following about his character George on Seinfeld:

> **[Jason Alexander:]** The character is unlovable.
>   He is a you know, he's a jerky, schmucky little character.
>   All right? He's just a buffoon.
>   He's so unappealing that to buy that there was a marriage - that's sustained at all
>
> **[Larry David:]** - All right, first of all, why is he unappealing? People loved the character.
>
> **[Jason Alexander:]** Because he's selfish, he's stupid, he lies - Yeah, but people he's not stupid.
>   he's abrasive, he's inept.

In an [off-show interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4SgIH4tTtRo), Jason has admitted realising George is based on an alter ego of Larry David after a few episodes of Seinfeld. Is that something Jason in Curb also knows and is he just teasing Larry or is the narrative that Curb's Jason Alexander does not know / realise this?

This is relevant because, in the transcript above, he's basically mocking Larry by extension. Seinfeld's George is based on Larry and by mocking George he's commenting on Larry's character traits.

It's obvious that this is done on purpose in the Curb episode, but it's not clear if the Jason character in Curb does this on purpose or if he doesn't realise this (which is weird because everyone who's seen Seinfeld and the previous Curb episodes do know).

Comment: I haven't watched either series, but I think you are mis-using the term "alter-ego". I think, from piecing together everything you've written, something like "...George Costanza is based on Larry David?" Otherwise, it implies that Larry David and George Constanza are physically the same person, whereas I believe George is played by Jason Alexander. Hence, George is an alter-ego of Jason Alexander, not Larry David. c.f Batman is an alter-ego of Bruce Wayne.

Comment: @Darren yea it was written a bit poorly. George's character is actually based on an alter ego of Larry David and it's portrayed in Seinfeld by Jason Alexander. In the Curb show, it's just the two, Jason the actor and Larry the producer as his alter ego (I think, though he might also just be himself, I'm not sure).

Comment: Jason and Larry had a similar exchange in Season 2, [the scene is on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGSVaSbFMH4). The "Curb" version of Jason does seem to know that some of George's actions were inspired by Larry's real life.

Comment: @Oliver_C thanks for finding that, I knew it was there somewhere. If you'd combine that extra piece into an answer I think it's as conclusive as we're going to get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the overarching themes of Curb is that almost every person larry is in contact with will eventually grow to dislike him. Because he is - simply - a selfish prick most of the time (and also has alot of quirks to go along with it).

Jason Alexander is special in many ways. He is basically the person that merged with the character George Costanza (who is in many ways similar to Larry David in Curb). So if any person on earth would be able to cope with Larry, it should be him. 
Him speaking so low of George is similar to Larry saying it to himself.
This is one level of humor in episode.

It is also commonly known that Jason Alexander is actually quite a decent, nice and intelligent person. It is very "out of character" of him to speak so harshly of another person. And it is also very "out of character" for him not to realize the relation between Larry and George.
This is another level of humor in this episode.

Additionally complaining as an actor about the *most successful role of his entire career* is - in a way - something George Costanza would have done in a similar situation. Because he was never happy with the hand he was dealt. No matter how good it was.
Basically all three characters in the scene are versions of the same character: Larry, George and Jason. They all share the same flaws in this scene. Yet they are completely opposed to each other.
Which adds one more level of humor to the scene.

And finally, if he is really aware of the connection between Larry and George, then it is simply a very cheeky of insulting Larry.
And Larry failing in what he does is yet another layer of humor of the series.

It doesnt really matter whether he does it on purpose or not. the ambivalence of it has its own value.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Jason Alexander learned that in first season.

This a video of interview with Jason Alexander who say that in first 8 episodes he had a scene where he doubted "reality" of it and Larry David said that it was exactly as it happened to him and how he reacted.

And a cherry on top

A recording of Curb your Enthusiasm with Seinfield Reunion where Larry David IS playing George. Where everyone admit that they knew that George is Based on Larry own experience.

Comment: The OP's question is about the "Curb" version of Jason, not the real life Jason.

Comment: @Oliver_C That's the cherry on top. Curb your enthusiasm when Curb Jason Alexander is talking about knowing it.